# A circular motion problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, centripetal-force

> A car goes on a horizontal circular road of radius $R$, the speed increasing at a constant rate $\frac{dv}{dt}=a(constant)$. The friction coefficient of the tyre is $\mu$. Find the speed at which the car will skid.
>   For vertical equilibrium, the normal force $\mathcal{N}=mg$, where $m$ is the mass of the car. For skid, $\frac{mv^2}{R}-f=ma=\frac{mv^2}{R}-\mu mg$.

Now it is well known that $v=\sqrt{\mu  gR}$, but it does not help me. I cannot proceed from here. The answer is pretty weird and it seems like i require integration as the answer possesses a lot of squares. So i tried differentiating but it takes me nowhere. Can you please help me? 
Note: Please do not close this or mark it as opinion based because it is not any homework. I simply am fond of physics so like doing problems and i encountered this one. I am just asking for help or the strategy.

Comment: Hi Shamim and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: You already told me that :◇

Comment: This is not homework... i am just stuck with it... jt feels bad, i really tried, even a good hont will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are not arriving at the answer because you haven't considered the tangential acceleration which will provide a pseudo force. 
So there are two forces acting on the car is the centrifugal force and a tangential force(ma) due to tangential acceleration a .
The car will skid when the frictional force equals the resultant of other forces acting on the car.
$ f_max = F_{net}$
Now $F_{net}$ on the car is the resultant of centrifugal force and tangential force.
$$ \mu mg= \sqrt{ (\frac{mv^2}{r})^2 + (ma)^2}$$
$$ \mu ^2 m^2g^2= (\frac{mv^2}{r})^2 + (ma)^2$$
$$ \mu ^2 g^2= (\frac{v^2}{r})^2 + (a)^2 $$
$$ (\mu ^2 g^2-a^2)r^2= v^4 $$
$$v= ((\mu ^2 g^2-a^2)r^2)^{\frac{1}{4}} $$
The formula that you mentioned $v= \sqrt{\mu Rg} $
Is valid for constant speed but here due to the acceleration " a" the speed changes